# My nectarines looks sick - what to do?

Tags: fruit-trees, diseases

Our young nectarine tree just started to give fruits (after we managed to [save it from the hyraxes](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/39295/how-to-protect-my-nectarine-tree-from-hyraxes)), but the fruits look sick - they are browny and sticky. Also, many leaves have small holes in them:

[image]

[image]

What is it and what can we do?

Comment: First thing to do: remove it quickly, not to spread the disease. Second: wait here for an answer of the real cause.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Remove what? The fruit or the tree?

Comment: The fruit. You cannot eat it, in any case. The tree is healthy (which confuse me), and you can cure it (e.g. with chemicals). But you do no want poison on what you eat (chemical or natural).